# Using unicode (Hebrew characters) with regular expression

Tags: python, regex, unicode

I wrote script that find expressions in web page:

```
import sre, urllib2, sys, BaseHTTPServer
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-    
address = sys.argv[1]
web_handle = urllib2.urlopen(address)
website_text = website_handle.read()    
matches = sre.findall(u"עברית", website_text)
for item in matches:
    print iten
```

This script works if I use a "regular" regular expression (without Hebrew characters) and doesn't match anything if I use them. 
What am I doing wrong?

*edit*
example:
url = https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Countries

Comment: Just how does it not work?  Do you get an error message?  Does it fail to match anything at all?  Does it match things that aren't really the same?  Please provide examples.

Comment: Doesn't match anything at all

Comment: Which version of Python are you using, and could you give us a URL to test on? Also, just a quick note that `nsregularexpression` refers to an Apple specific implementation of regex. I swapped out that tag for the standard regex tag for you.

Comment: I don't know -- this is pretty straightforward.  Can you try some simpler examples, such as finding a single letter (say, beth or gimel) in a short string?  Can you find the string in a copy of itself, such as sre.findall(u"עברית", u"עברית") ?

Comment: @Prune - I pasted `re.findall(u"עברית", u"עברית")` right into the 2.7.9 REPL and it worked fine. I don't think we'll be able to answer this without Sanich gives us a URL to test on.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare Added example in the question

Comment: @Prune yes, sre.findall(u"עברית", u"עברית") works fine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to ensure that the *input* string is also in UTF8 format.

Use `unicode` function with `utf-8` as second argument:

```
website_text = unicode(website_text, "utf-8")
```

Everything should be in consistent encoding for unicode to work in Python 2.